# Hosting multiple sites - Mask URL?

Tags: htaccess, url, redirects, web-hosting

I have a hosting account where I have my main site (**www.mainsite.com** points to root folder), and a subfolder **xpto.com**, where I want to  have another site (**www.xpto.com**).

I can access **www.anothersite.com** by typing **www.mainsite.com/xpto.com**. Also, using cPanel, I've redirected **www.xpto.com** to **www.mainsite.com/xpto.com**.

My question is: is there a way to prevent **www.xpto.com** access by typing **www.mainsite.com/xpto.com**, so it can be accessed only by typing **www.xpto.com**?

EDIT: also, I don't want to **www.xpto.com** to be accessed via **www.xpto.mainsite.com**. Any help?

Hope I have explained this clearly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If mod_rewrite is enabled on your server you may create following **.htaccess** file in the folder `root_folder/xpto.com/`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mainsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

This will check if the request URL ends with `mainsite.com` and deny access if it does.

**EDIT**: If you want to return a **404 Not Found**, you may use this RewriteRule (first two lines stay the same):

```
RewriteRule .* - [R=404]
```

You can also insert other [HTTP status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) instead of **404** (but replace the dash with an actual URL for redirects).

Comment: Thank you Beat. I tried, and it worked, I mean, I get a Forbiden error when accessing xpto.mainsite.com or mainsite.com/xpto.com. However, is it possible to customize this error, for instance, change it to "Not Found" error? Thanks!